# jQuery OwlCarousel v1.3.3 looping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery OwlCarousel v1.3.3 in one of my project but now client wants if we click on last owl dot, 1st slide of owl will be shown to next last slide like we have on Owl Carousel v2.2.0. Do we have any option in OwlCarousel v1.3.3 to do this effect?

Below is the link of demo page of OwlCarousel v2.2.0 effect.

**[LINK](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html)**

Many thanks in advance and sorry if I'm not clear to you.

Comment: I believe the only option out-of-the box is in V2.

Comment: @AndFisher at this moment we can't take any risk to change library :(

Comment: For a project I worked on we bit the bullet and upgraded to v2 for this exact feature. OwlCarousel was abandoned at one point but (apparently) recently has a new owner on Github.